# How to invoke client CustomValidation on multiple TextBox controls each time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have three text boxes in ASP.NET 4.7.2 in a , each with its own CustomValidator (calling the same JS function) to make sure the values enter in them are in ascending order.

The validation is client side using JavaScript which triggers upon exiting a Text Box.

```
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
           <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" runat="server"
                                ClientValidationFunction="JSValidate"
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox1" Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="!"/>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
           <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv2" runat="server"
                                ClientValidationFunction="JSValidate"
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox2" Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="!"/>
      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
           <asp:CustomValidator ID="cv3" runat="server"
                                ClientValidationFunction="JSValidate"
                                ControlToValidate="TextBox3" Display="Dynamic" 
                                ErrorMessage="!"/>
```

The Javascript validation function is registered via the following code in the .cs

```
   string customValidation= @"function JSValidate(){
      
      //if values in all three text boxes are in ascending order, return true
     
      //otherwise return false
   }"

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "ConfigurationCustomValidationScripts", customValidation, true);
```

[image]

This is working in that when TextBox2 value is out of place, upon enter 500 and exit the text box the user sees the validation error of red exclamation mark:

[image]

But when we modify the value in TextBox3, the error exclamation in TextBox2 remains because its CustomValidator never get called, it only get clear if the user changes value to a new value (ex. 501)

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated, in laymen term I want ControlToValidate = TextBox1, TextBox2 and TexBox3 each time instead of specific control.  So when the user enters 700 in TextBox3, the web form automatically revalidates all text boxes and therefore removes the red exclamation mark from TextBox2.

I read up on ValidationGroup, but this is is a PostBack and requite a button click to cause the validation.  I also looked into ValidationSummary but that is more one the entire form instead of showing error beside the offending text box.

Answer (score 1):

For a situation this complex, you might consider doing your validation in javascript without validator controls. You could use javascript to check (and set/clear the warning exclamation for) all three boxes when any one of them is exited, and you could also run that same javascript check on your submit button so you can prevent the postback from happening if any problems remain. It's a little more work to achieve, but I don't think Validators are designed to consider multiple controls, it's a one to one kind of thing.